# How to sort JavaScript array by height and get only print height in console

Tags: javascript

This is my data.

```
var data = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"24", "height":"5.2"},
    {"firstName":"Sam", "lastName":"Sam", "age":"28", "height":"6.0"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"25", "height":"5.8"},
    {"firstName":"Willam", "lastName":"Will", "age":"22", "height":"5.2"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"23", "height":"6.2"}
];
```

And this is what I have tried.

```
var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b){
    return a.height - b.height;                
});
console.log(data.sort(sorted));
```

Comment: Please, you need to read this before ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This is a poor writted question

Comment: You're sorting your data once, then sorting it again passing the sorted results as the comparison function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
var data = [
            {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe", "age":"24", "height":"5.2"},
            {"firstName":"Sam", "lastName":"Sam", "age":"28", "height":"6.0"},
            {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith", "age":"25", "height":"5.8"},
            {"firstName":"Willam", "lastName":"Will", "age":"22", "height":"5.2"},
            {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones", "age":"23", "height":"6.2"}
            ];

data.sort(function(a,b){
     return a.height - b.height;
});
console.log(data)
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
console.log(data[i]['height']);
}
```

Please refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a59o2m9j/2/) for ascending order.

Please refer to this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a59o2m9j/3/) for descending order.

Comment: Sahil gupta thanks for speed reply. I have done sorting part I just want to get only sorted height values in console.

Comment: Hey Thanks Sahil gupta your code is simple. can you tell me how it works for descending order.

Comment: Updated the answer !! The difference being in the sorting technique!! Please have a look at the fiddle!!

Answer (score 0):

```js
Try this...

var data = [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": "24",
  "height": "5.2"
}, {
  "firstName": "Sam",
  "lastName": "Sam",
  "age": "28",
  "height": "6.0"
}, {
  "firstName": "Anna",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "age": "25",
  "height": "5.8"
}, {
  "firstName": "Willam",
  "lastName": "Will",
  "age": "22",
  "height": "5.2"
}, {
  "firstName": "Peter",
  "lastName": "Jones",
  "age": "23",
  "height": "6.2"
}];

function sortByKey(array, key) {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a[key];
    var y = b[key];
    return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
  });
}

data = sortByKey(data, 'height');
console.log(data);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data[i]['height']);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ejemhj50/

Comment: Awesome this is working can you please explain me how this works. and let me know how to sort it in descending order.

Comment: Change this line to descending order  return ((x > y) ? -1 : ((x < y) ? 1 : 0));

Comment: Thanks for the reply Deena.